# How to use openstack components in my web app

Tags: java, cloud, openstack

I want to create a web app using OpenStack which will collect data from virtual sensors(programs that will generate dummy data) and then I will provide users operations on that data and i want to bill them accordingly.
I know about the Openstack components like Keystone, Nova, Glance but I don't know how to utilize them in a Web app and how to use it there.
I installed devstack on my system and found out a java library: [OpenStack4j](http://www.openstack4j.com/) to interact with the openstack.
But the problem is that I don't know how to use Openstack components for implementing the different functionalities of my app. e.g: For Logging into my Web App I will use Keystone, For making and storing my virtual sensors I will make programs and store then in X component, For billing I will use Y component to read the amount of data fetched from DB.
Also, is Amazon AWS simpler if I want to do the same thing there?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to read through the [Writing Your First OpenStack Application](http://developer.openstack.org/firstapp-libcloud/getting_started.html). That guide is in Python as there isn't a version in Java yet. Nonetheless, I think it would help you a lot to read through it and think about how you would do similar things with a Java OpenStack SDK of your choice, like [OpenStack4j](http://www.openstack4j.com/) or [jclouds](http://jclouds.apache.org/guides/openstack/).